# $\alpha$ is unique if $f(x) \leq \alpha \leq g(x)$ for all $x$ and $\lim_{x\to a} ( g(x)-f(x)) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, real-numbers

Let's say we have a function $f$ and another one as $g$, both are functions of, say, $x$. Let $\alpha$ be the number which lies between $f$ and $g$ for every $x$, that is 
$$
∀x ( f(x) \leq \alpha \leq g(x) )$$

It is a given condition that $$\lim_{x\to a} ( g(x)-f(x)) = 0$$

Now, I want to know what does it mean to say "$\alpha$ is the only number in between $f$ and $g$ in the limiting process as $x$ goes to $a$". My understanding speaks like this: The given condition that difference between $g$ and $f$ reduces to zero as $x$ goes to $a$ rigorously means that we can make $g(x)$ as close to $f(x)$ as we desire, and since $\alpha$ is always going to lie between them, a stage would come when $\alpha$ will be the only number in between them.

But the flaw in my understanding is that it violates the elementary statement "Between any two numbers there lies infinitely many numbers, no matter how they close they are". So, no matter how close we can make $g$ to $f$ there always gonna lie infinitely many numbers not just $\alpha$.

Comment: You should see that the room between $f, g$ is reducing as $x\to a$. If we have two fixed numbers lying between them then the room size can't be less than the distance between these two.

Comment: It is possible that there are infinitely many pairs of numbers $a, b$ with $a, b$ both dependent on $x$ and $a<b$ which lie between $f(x), g(x) $. The issue comes when we try to put the same two fixed numbers between $f, g$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, I agree that they will not be able to come closer than $\beta - \alpha$. But saying that there lies a number between $f$ and $g$ as limit $x$ goes to $a$ means that they cannot be equal, $\alpha$ lies between them.

Comment: Well $f, g$ may or may not be equal for some value of $x$. If they are equal then in any case they must equal $\alpha$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can you please explain how they will be equal to $\alpha$ when limit $x$ goes to $a$? It’s something I really want to understand.

Comment: I got that both $f$ and $g$ will approach $\alpha$. I used squeeze Theorem.

Comment: Use Squeeze on $0\leq \alpha - f(x) \leq g(x) - f(x) $ and get $f(x) \to \alpha $ and similarly note $0\leq g(x) - \alpha\leq g(x) - f(x) $.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that there are to distinct such numbers, $\alpha$ and $\beta$. You can assume, without loss of generality, that $\alpha<\beta$. Then, for each $x$, $g(x)-f(x)\geqslant\beta-\alpha>0$, and therefore you will not have$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)-g(x)=0.$$Yes, between any two distinct real numbers, there are infinitely many real numbers. So, for a *fixed* real number $x$, if $g(x)>f(x)$, there are infinitely many real numbers between them. But you cannot deduce from this that there are infinitely many real numbers $\alpha$ such that $f(x)\leqslant\alpha\leqslant g(x)$ for *every* number $x$.

Comment: Thank you for answering me, please consider the typo “to” instead of “two”. Sir, I couldn’t understand this inequality $$f(x)-g(x)\geq \beta - \alpha \gt 0$$. Please explain it.

Comment: You always have $f(x)\leqslant\alpha<\beta\leqslant g(x)$. But then, since $g(x)\geqslant\beta$ and $f(x)\leqslant\alpha$, $g(x)-f(x)\geqslant\beta-\alpha$.

Comment: The explanation in second paragraph is the essence here. +1 for the same.

Answer (score 2):

**First Approach**

I understand your remark.

1-Indeed for two given, **fixed**real number $f(x) $ and $g(x) $, there exists infinitely number between them.

2-Yet, here we are dealing with a sequence $${f(x) - g(x)}_{x \in V(a)} $$ i. e. all values of the difference between f and g with $x$ is a neighborhood of $a$.

**What is the key is the limit**

Here the **uniqueness** comes from the limit.

Indeed if $f(x)-g(x) \to 0$ when $x\to a$.
 Supposing that $f$ and $g$ converge and $f \leq\alpha \leq g(x) $ for all $x$.

Then  because $f$ and $g$ are supposed to converge and 
$$f(x)-g(x) \to 0$$

$f$  and $g$ have the same limit say $\lambda$

Thus taking the limit in the inequality  $f(x) \leq\alpha \leq g(x) $

We finally have $$\lambda\leq \alpha \leq \lambda$$

i. e.

Then $$\alpha=\lim_a f=\lim_a g$$ hence its uniqueness.

**Second approach**

More intuitively you know you can approach $f$ to $g$ as close as you want thanks to 
$f(x)-g(x) \to 0$

Imagine there are two numbers that want to take the role of $\alpha$, say $\alpha$ and $\beta $ with $
\alpha<\beta$.

Then $f$ is always under $\alpha$ and $g$ is always over $\beta$.

$$ f\leq \alpha<\beta \leq g$$

Imaging, between  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ you get a vacuum, like a nonmansland, for $f$ and $g$ so they can't meet i. e. you can't have
$f(x)-g(x) \to 0$.

Rigorously it means that $f<\dfrac{ \alpha +\beta} {2}<\dfrac{\alpha+3\beta} {4}<g$ taking the arithmetic average between $ \alpha$ and $\beta$ and therefore between $b$ and $\dfrac{ \alpha+\beta} {2}$.

So $$\forall x, |f(x) - g(x) |>\dfrac{\beta- \alpha} {4}  $$

which is contradictory with :

$$f(x)-g(x) \to 0$$.

Comment: It’s just a wonderful answer, thanks. Can you please explain what happened after (in second approach) $$f \leq a \lt b \leq g$$ ?

Comment: (I think if you could change $a$ with $\alpha$ form very beginning, then it would become easier to read and more upvotes will be achieved).

Comment: I modified, I was meaning that you get (as an image) a no access zone for $f$ and $g$, and because there are suppose to join at $x=a$ we get a contradiction.